# Посчитать день месяца

Tags: linux, c, время

Есть задача, нужно посчитать день месяца имея:

1. Год
2. Месяц
3. Номер недели в месяце
4. Номер дня в неделе

Даты меньше 2021 года не учитываются в задаче.

Пример: При подаче 2021 год, Август, Первая неделя, Вторник результат будет 3

Думал использовать strptime(), но она не работает с номером недели в месяце. Поэтому, наверно, сначала, нужно посчитать номер недели в году из входных данных, но тут я застрял. Помогите, пожалуйста. Можно, наверно даже, и так посчитать, без strptime()

Comment: Вам известен год и месяц - постройте календарь на этот месяц. Дальше научитесь выделять неделю и решить, как именно их считать (то есть, если первое число это воскресенье, то второе число это понедельник второй недели? и понедельник первой недели тогда что?) А дальше задача будет элементарной

Comment: 2021 год же начинается с пятницы. Разве не её лучше считать первым днём первой недели?

Comment: возможно. но пока первым днем недели могут быть суббота, воскресенье и понедельник. О пятнице я пока не слышал

Comment: Так мы же потом можем смещение сделать с пятницы в нормальный день недели, когда неделю в году посчитаем

Comment: но я не понимаю, зачем? у нас же номер недели в месяце, а не годе.

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем правильно объяснил  задачу. Месяц должен быть любой, из любого года > 2021. Поэтому я и решил, что проще перейти к номеру недели в году (0 .. 52). Разве я могу построить просто так календарь на март 2025 года?

Comment: да, можно просто так взять и построить календарь на произвольный месяц. Если сильно далеко в будущее не заходить, то это не сложно

Comment: Хорошо, с чего мне начать, чтобы это сделать? В общих чертах описать алгоритм можете?

Comment: посмотрите на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517192/c-day-of-week-for-given-date/40517482 - узнаете, как по дате получить день недели. Рассчитываете день недели на 1 число нужного месяца и готово

Comment: А может, считая неделю начинающейся с первого дня месяца? И тогда это просто что-то вроде найти день 2-го вторника?

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём трудность. Вам надо преобразовать ваш условный Вторник во смещение внутри недели (если начинается в понедельник, то 2), и потом добавит смещение начала месяца, например, если это воскресенье, то 3, если это пятница, то задача не имеет решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуемся структурой

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;    /* Seconds (0-60) */
   int tm_min;    /* Minutes (0-59) */
   int tm_hour;   /* Hours (0-23) */
   int tm_mday;   /* Day of the month (1-31) */
   int tm_mon;    /* Month (0-11) */
   int tm_year;   /* Year - 1900 */
   int tm_wday;   /* Day of the week (0-6, Sunday = 0) */
   int tm_yday;   /* Day in the year (0-365, 1 Jan = 0) */
   int tm_isdst;  /* Daylight saving time */
};
```

объявленной в <time.h>. Выясним время (time_t) начала первого дня интересуещего нас месяца:

```
struct tm wrk;
struct tm *first_day;
time_t tt;

wrk.tm_year = year; // Год нам задан
wrl.tm_mon = mon;   // Тоже известен
wrk.tm_mday = 1;    // Начало месяца

/* 
Функция mktime() преобразует временную структуру с разбивкой, выраженную как местное время, в представление календарного времени. Функция игнорирует значения, предоставленные вызывающей стороной в полях tm_wday и tm_yday.
*/

tt = mktime(&wrk);


/*
Теперь, с помощью функции localtime() можно выполнить обратное действие - из времени начала первого дня месяца получить день недели этого дня.
*/
first_day = localtime(tt);

/*
В поле first_day->tm_wday содержится именно то, что нам и нужно - номер (0-6) дня недели первого числа заданного года и месяца.

В месяце может быть от 4-х до 6-и недель. Вычислим СМЕЩЕНИЕ воскресенья 
в первой неделе месяца, относительно первого числа. 
*/

int wd_offset;
wd_offset = -first_day->tm_wday; // Обратите внимание на знак "минус"!


/*
Теперь берём номер недели, умножаем на 7 и прибавляем смещение
*/

day_of_moon = 7 * week_num + wd_offset;
```

Как-то так, приблизительно :-)

Comment: Не видна работа с високосными годами, например.

Comment: @0andriy - "работа с високосными годами," А что, в високосные  годы в неделе не 7 дней?

Comment: там не всегда нужно умножать на 7. по вашему алгоритму на первой неделе мы всегда будем сбиваться на вторую, но это не главная проблема, т.к. она легко решается. Плюс нужно посчитать последний день месяца, т.к., например, если последний день вторник, а мы ищем среду, то нужно искать на предыдущей неделе. Есть ещё пара проблем, но не суть. Задачу я решил. За ответ спасибо, помог.

Comment: И ещё вроде как нужно использовать функцию strptime(), чтобы wday первого числа месяца заполнить, хотя, наверно, localtime() тоже это делает